# WildFly: Quick Way to Determine Which Version of JBossWS Is in Use?

Tags: jboss, wildfly, jbossws

What's the quickest way to determine which version of JBossWS is in use in a WildFly installation?

I have a WildFly 10 installation, and when I search various files for version numbers pertaining to JBossWS, I see different things depending on where I look.

Examples:

- {jboss-install-dir}\runtimes\jboss-eap\modules\system\layers\base\org\jboss\as\webservices\main\module.xml references jbossws-cxf-resources-5.1.3.SP1-redhat-1-wildfly1000.jar
- {jboss-install-dir}\runtimes\jboss-eap\modules\system\layers\base\jboss\ws\api\main\module.xml references jbossws-api-1.0.3.Final-redhat-1.jar
- {jboss-install-dir}\runtimes\jboss-eap\modules\system\layer\base\org\jboss\ws\common\main\module.xml references jbossws-common-3.1.1.Final-redhat-1.jar

Are any of these the JBossWS version, or should I be looking elsewhere? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think JBossWS version is the same as asking JBoss WS-CXF, since JBossWS takes apache-cxf and integrates it to Wildfly. So the answer is 5.1.3.SP1

You can also check https://access.redhat.com/articles/112673